# How to get the byte encoding for ASCII characters with hex <= 0x20?

Tags: c, string, assembly, char, ascii

The first 0x20 chars in the ASCII scheme seem to be related to functions such as (cancel) and (escape). Say I wanted to get 0x18 as a single byte encoding in a specific place in my input C-String. How would I accomplish this?

I've tried some characters that seem to be HTML related. My only idea is to try to use some of the assembly instructions partial encodings to get 0x18, but I'm not sure how I would do this in an input string setting.

Comment: In C and assembly, it's trivial to set any byte you want to any integer value.  Like `char foo[] = { 0x18, ' ', 'H', 0};` in C.  Or like `str[2] = 0x18;`.  The byte encoding for ASCII character 0x18 is a single byte with value 0x18...  If you're asking about how to type that as terminal input, that depends on the terminal.  If you redirect input from a file, you can of course prepare any binary file data you want for a program to read from stdin.

Comment: You can also just embed a specific byte in a string as a hex escape, like this: `char *s = "hi\x18there";`

Comment: For convenience, C _recognises_ some "escaped characters" in C strings as a few of the ASCII "control codes" (eg: \n is LF, \r is CR, \t is TAB.) You can use hex as shown in other responses, or you can embed octal escape sequences. `"hello\040world\041\015\012"` is the same as `"hello world!\r\n"` Only use this if there is a particularly good reason. "Magic numbers" make code less readable...

Answer (score 2):

```c
char x = 0x18;
```

or

```
char x = '\x18';
```

In strings,

```
char *x = "\x18";
```